# Усилить чувствительность микрофона

Tags: xamarin

Я пишу приложение для видеозвонков на Xamarin.Forms. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, что на громкой связи собеседника слышно лишь тогда, когда он подносит микрофон ко рту почти вплотную, а в таком положении очень неудобно показывать видео с камеры. Как можно усилить чувствительность микрофона программно на время звонка? Или, как альтернатива, как можно усилить воспроизводимый звук на другой стороне, если она и так стоит на максимуме?